# How to get specified value from DB?

Tags: php, database

How can I get this value from DB as string or int?

[PHPMyAdmin http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/6388/gr55.jpg](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/6388/gr55.jpg)

I've tried this:

```
$var = $this->db->query("SELECT SUBSTRING(`category_id`, 1, 3) 
AS `category_id` FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category 
WHERE merlion_id = 'Q1' 
ORDER BY category_id ASC");
```

And then I've checked it with `var_dump` and receive this:

```
var_dump($var);
object(stdClass)#26 (3) { ["row"]=> array(1) { ["category_id"]=> string(3) "859" } ["rows"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["category_id"]=> string(3) "859" } } ["num_rows"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: Whereas BD stands for DB?

Comment: Err.. you got it. What's your *real* question?

Comment: What is that `SUBSTRING` doing there?

Comment: I need to get exactly 859. How to convert this Object to the simple value?

Comment: what's wrong with `select category_id ...`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I've tried this but the result is the same - it returns object. I need string or int.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think his problem is that he does not know how to extract that column value from the object. user2655556: Please see my or Bart Friederichs' answer if they fit your problem.

Comment: @ComFreek: what kind of "object"? It's seems to be a regular table with just an integer column. As far as I know MySQL does not have any object oriented extensions (like e.g. Postgres or Oracle). I don't understand what an "object" has to do with an integer column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The PHP result object he got by querying the database (probably using MySQL(i) or PDO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do `SUBSTRING`:

```
$var = $this->db->query("`category_id`FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category 
WHERE merlion_id = 'Q1' 
ORDER BY category_id ASC");
```

Then, you have it, you don't "convert" the object, you take what you need from it:

```
$category_id = $var->row["category_id"];
```

I suggest you dive into basic PHP before you continue with your database-driven application. This is all trivial stuff. There are many good tutorials out there, also about PHP object oriented programming. Most notably the [PHP documentation site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
echo $var->row['category_id'];
```

You can also simplify your query:

```
$var = $this->db->query("SELECT `category_id` 
AS `category_id` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category` 
WHERE merlion_id = 'Q1' 
LIMIT 1");
```

- Added backticks around the table name
- Removed your *ORDER* clause. You do not need it if you only have one dataset whose *merlion_id* is *Q1*.
- Added *LIMIT* clause since you only want one dataset.